# How to ensure Visual studio updates the registry when installing compiler

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio, installation, mex

I'm having a frustrating time trying to get the visual studio compiler up and running. I'm trying to install the visual studio compiler to use with matlab.

After installing build tools from [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), for some reason, the registry is not updated and matlab is not able to find the compiler. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling after cleaning the registry using ccleaner but that doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Execute `regedit.exe`, and look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7` In value "`14.0`", in my machine data is:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\     ,Compiler location is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I'm using Matlab R2017a. The registry path you suggested doesn't exist in my case. I have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ and under that there are 2 folders - 14.0 and debugger.

Comment: Also, my cl.exe files are located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin and in the sub-directories of the bin folder amd64, amd64_arm, amd64_x86

Comment: Matlab Compiler configuration is in XML file `msvcpp2015.xml` in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016a\bin\win64\mexopts\ You can find all definitions in that file.

Comment: Sorry, I lost you there. I am not sure what to do with that file exactly.

Comment: I thought about replacing the line `<hklmExists path="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" name="14.0" />` to point right registry location (I am not sure it's going to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the new version of visual studio 2017 doesn't actually update the registry or something like that (see here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2813/cant-find-registry-entries-for-visual-studio-2017.html) .
I ended up installing the older version of visual studio community (VS 2015 with updates) and matlab was able to find it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your sharing, please mark it as answer when you have free time, it will help other community members to easier search this useful information :)

Comment: Thanks Sara. Will do.